# Is there a workaround for Firefox not calling onunload when a window is closed?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, dom-events

As some of you know Firefox does not call onunload in if the window or tab is closed.  Do you know of any sort of work around?

Basically, I need to know that user is done with the window, so I can free a lock.  Do you all have any suggestions?

I have heard robust code should not use onunload.  Is there some obvious alternative?

Comment: How does the lock get set? You should make sure that it gets removed after some time, if not somebody might just spam your server with HTTP requests that create a lock and you end up with a ton of locks that will never be released.

Comment: Well, the lock is session based.  And you can only set one per session.

Comment: They is not currently a timeout, but I may add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your lock is on the server, make the lock time out after (say) 30 seconds and have a function on the window automatically renew the lock every 25 seconds.  Call the function from a setInterval.  When the window is closed, the interval is canceled and the lock will timeout 15 seconds later (on average).  Crude but effective.

Comment: I don't think it is very crude.  I kind of think well of the idea.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  onunload is NOT robust, if only because the electricity to the browsing computer could be turned off (or it could be disconnected from the Internet or the building could fall into the ocean) so onunload cannot possibly be called and you need to make sure that *your* systems continue to function properly.